# SharedPreferences not saving value

Tags: android

Here's the code that's causing me issues:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView lblName;
    private View.OnClickListener droidTapListener;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean prefsShown = prefs.getBoolean("haveShownPrefs", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (!prefsShown){
            //launch the preferences activity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Preferences.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        init(prefs);

    }

    private void init(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblName);
        lblName.setText(prefs.getString("userName",""));
    }

}

public class Preferences extends Activity {

    private EditText txtName;
    private Button btnDone;
    private View.OnClickListener droidTapListener;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("haveShownPrefs", true);
        ed.commit();
        init(prefs, ed);

    }

    private void init(SharedPreferences prefs, SharedPreferences.Editor ed) {

        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        ed.putString("userName", txtName.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();
        droidTapListener = new View.OnClickListener()  {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(droidTapListener);
    }

}
```

Here's the XML in case I missing something:

preferences.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".Preferences">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:id="@+id/lblName"
                android:layout_column="3"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_column="9"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:id="@+id/btnDone"
                android:layout_column="10"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".Preferences">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/lblName"
                android:layout_column="5"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The problem is that on the MainActivity when I go to print the name on lblName it's blank, I've tested on Prefereces doing:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    btnDone.setText(txtName.getText().toString());
}
```

And it works fine, so the issue is with the SharedPreferences. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the preferences.xml one time manually? With an explorer

Comment: @Oli I'm not sure what you mean, if I open preferences.xml with a webbrowser then it just shows me the xml code and I have indeed checked it for errors.
I've added the xml to the question, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Preferences`, the `init` function reads the contents of `txtName` and writes the value to the `SharedPreferences`. The only place you call `init` is `onCreate`. At that point, the user hasn't yet had a chance to type any test into `txtName`. You need to read its value later, after the user has typed into it. Depending on your application, you might want to do this from the button listener, or perhaps from the `onPause` method of `Preferences`, so that the value will be saved however the user chooses to leave this activity (for example, by pressing **back** or **home**).

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem and it was incredibly silly of me, also thank you for letting me know about onPause!

Comment: [This page from the official Android developer training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) should help you decide whether to use `onPause` or not.